# strtotime returns current year when input is in the format of YYYY and the value is greater then 1999

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm not sure that this is a bug since after searching I can't find any duplicate experiences- however, this one has me stumped.

While in the midst of a (rather painful) script that is intended to take a bunch of freetext records and convert them to useful date records, my trusty friend strtotime() seems to have let me down.

For testing purposes, I boiled the code down to this:

```
<?=date('Y', strtotime("1999"));?>
```

Output shows: 1999

```
<?=date('Y', strtotime("1981"));?>
```

Output shows: 1981

```
<?=date('Y', strtotime("2001"));?>
```

Output shows: 2012

```
<?=date('Y', strtotime("2021"));?>
```

Output shows: 2012

Everything seems fine until the input exceeds "1999"- From that point on, every year before and after the current one returns the current year (2012)

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: strtotime has never been trusty, and it's most definitely not your friend. it's just a leach, hanging on for dear life, trash talking the better alternatives like DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per PHP's [date/time format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) docs:

> The "Year (and just the year)" format only works if a time string has already been found -- otherwise this format is recognised as HH MM.

(2nd last note on the page).

Comment: Had to go with the answer that called me out on not RTFM carefully enough. Thanks all, very helpful.

Comment: Excuse me but what does it mean for time string to be already found in regards to passing year to `strtotime`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that it is parsed as time, what you can see if you use `date('c')` instead of `date('Y');`.

```
php > var_dump(date('c', strtotime("2001")));
string(25) "2012-02-23T20:01:00+01:00"
```

You should pass the value unambiguous for example `2012-01-01`.

Another solution is to use a function, that allows to specify the format of the given input, like [strptime()](http://php.net/strptime), or [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

```
php > echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', '2001')->format('c');
2001-02-23T22:29:56+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try prefixing the years with `Jan 1,`.

For example:

`<?=date('Y', strtotime("Jan 1, 2021"));?>` outputs `2021` as expected.

I'm supposing this is because certain years can be incorrectly parsed as month/day pairs, such as "2012" being interpreted as "December 20th of the current year".

If you want proof for yourself, try changing the date format to `r`:
`<?=date('r', strtotime('2001'));?>` gives `Thu, 23 Feb 2012 20:01:00`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo date('Y', strtotime("1/1/2001"));
echo date('Y', strtotime("1/1/2021"));
```

Using 4 digits as date can be interpreted as time, you should use a more specific format to make sure the function works as you expect it.
So 2021 is 20:21 (24h format) of 2012

Answer (score 0):

`$plaintext = '2004'; //'2004-11','2004-5','2004-5-1','2004/5-1','2004/08/10'`
`echo date('Y', strtotime(` 
    `(strlen($plaintext)==10?$plaintext:` 
        `(strlen($plaintext)==7? str_replace('-','/',$plaintext).'/01':` 
             `(strlen($plaintext)==4?$plaintext.'/01/01':$plaintext)` 
         `)`
`)));`